# how to change event in jquery a form tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace onsubmit event to onload event in jquery. Here is my HTML

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="NewShippingAddress" onsubmit="return ExpressCheckout.ChooseShippingAddress();">
```

I want this to be

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="NewShippingAddress" onload="return ExpressCheckout.ChooseShippingAddress();">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really elegant, but ..

```
var event = $("#NewShippingAddress").attr("onsubmit");
$("#NewShippingAddress").removeAttr("onsubmit");
$("#NewShippingAddress").attr("onload", event);
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish your goal, you can run your task when page loads and remove *onsubmit* and *onload* attributes `<from>` form tag. Just add this code snipped at the bottom of your `<body>` element.

**Native JavaScript way:**

This will bind an even listener **DOMContentLoaded** to your page document and will run event function when page finishes loading content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // This will be executed on page load
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        ExpressCheckout.ChooseShippingAddress();
    });
</script>
```

**jQuery way:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // This will be executed on page load
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ExpressCheckout.ChooseShippingAddress();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.